# Google Tag Manager click events not returning element ID

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

New to Google Tag Manager so forgive the incompetence. I added 'Click - All elements' trigger to all clicks to test out GTM. I need to get the element ID's using this but all I see is '
["u", "n", "d", "e", "f", "i", "n", "e", "d"]'[image]

The elements have ID's yet I cannot seem to see any of them? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: show html of element and gtm configuration, pls

Comment: The undefined "HTML ID" is not the id of the click element (that would be "Click ID"). HTML ID is a built in variable that "allows custom HTML tags to signal if they had succeeded or failed; used with tag sequencing", quoted from here: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7182738?hl=en. Your Click ID is empty, if you expect this to be otherwise than you might have nested HTML where the id is on an outer element and the click element is the inner nested element.

Comment: @EikePierstorff You were right. I am able to get the ID's now but under certain circumstances. It is very specific to what part of a button I click etc.... Thank you